# Custom Navigation Drawer where icons are visible when closed

Tags: android

### Is it possible to achieve this Style of navigation drawer in android

**State-1: When the Drawer is opened:** 
[image]

**State-2: when the Drawer is closed:**
[image]

Comment: Do you need to display icon when drawer is closed? If you then you have to manually set width for navigation drawer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can achieve it using [SlidingPaneLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html).
I am sharing the implementation in this answer.

Create a layout resource file and set SlidingPaneLayout as your parent view. SlidingPaneLayout requires two child views: a master view and a detail view. The master view will contain a list of all our menu options and the detail view will contain the content.

**content_main.xml**

```
    <!--Master fragment-->
    <fragment
        android:name="com.ng.anthony.mininavigationdrawer.MasterFragment"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_master">
    </fragment>

    <!--Detail layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

The master view is contained inside a fragment. When creating multi pane layouts, it is good practice to separate your panes in fragments. This keeps the code modular and each pane is contained in its own layout file. Add the master fragment class to your project.

**MasterFragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MasterFragment extends ListFragment {

    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_master, container);

        setListAdapter(new MenuListAdapter(R.layout.row_menu_action_item, getActivity(), MenuActionItem.values()));
        return view;
    }
}
```

Add the master fragment layout to your layout resources folder.

**fragment_master.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:divider="@null">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The master fragment contains a list view and uses an enumeration of menu options to populate the list.

**MenuActionItem.java**

```
public enum MenuActionItem {
    ITEM1,
    ITEM2,
    ITEM3,
    ITEM4,
    ITEM5
}
```

The master fragment also contains a custom array adapter that displays the list of menu options. The custom array adapter inflates a row layout for each menu option.

**MenuListAdapter.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MenuListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MenuActionItem> {

    int resource;
    Activity activity;

    public MenuListAdapter(int resource, Activity activity, MenuActionItem[] items) {
        super(activity, resource, items);

        this.resource = resource;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;

        if(rowView == null) {
            rowView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(resource, null);

            MenuItemViewHolder viewHolder = new MenuItemViewHolder();

            viewHolder.menuItemImageView = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_image_view);
            viewHolder.menuItemTextView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_text_view);

            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        MenuItemViewHolder holder = (MenuItemViewHolder)rowView.getTag();

        if(position == MenuActionItem.ITEM1.ordinal()) {
            holder.menuItemImageView.setImageDrawable(activity.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_payment_white_24dp));
            holder.menuItemTextView.setText(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.item1));
        }
        else if(position == MenuActionItem.ITEM2.ordinal()) {
            holder.menuItemImageView.setImageDrawable(activity.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pets_white_24dp));
            holder.menuItemTextView.setText(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.item2));
        }
        else if(position == MenuActionItem.ITEM3.ordinal()) {
            holder.menuItemImageView.setImageDrawable(activity.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_receipt_white_24dp));
            holder.menuItemTextView.setText(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.item3));
        }
        else if(position == MenuActionItem.ITEM4.ordinal()) {
            holder.menuItemImageView.setImageDrawable(activity.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_white_24dp));
            holder.menuItemTextView.setText(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.item4));
        }
        else if(position == MenuActionItem.ITEM5.ordinal()) {
            holder.menuItemImageView.setImageDrawable(activity.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_work_white_24dp));
            holder.menuItemTextView.setText(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.item5));
        }

        return rowView;
    }

    private static class MenuItemViewHolder {
        public ImageView menuItemImageView;
        public TextView menuItemTextView;
    }
}
```

Add the row layout.

**row_menu_action_item.xml**

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_image_view"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Run your project and you should see something like this. When you swipe your finger right, the master layout will appear.

[image: Mini navigation drawer]

To show the menu icons when the drawer is in the collapsed state, we simply add a margin left to the detail view. This shifts the detail view to the right revealing a portion of the master layout that is hidden underneath the detail view when the SlidingPaneLayout is in the collapsed state.

**content_main_margin_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Master fragment-->
    <fragment
        android:name="com.ng.anthony.mininavigationdrawer.MasterFragment"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_master">
    </fragment>

    <!--Detail layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="56dp">
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

Run your project again and this time you should see the menu icons on the left of the screen.

[image: Mini Navigation Drawer]

You can also check this **Sample project**:
https://github.com/nganthony/MiniNavigationDrawer

**Reference link:** 
http://nganthony.github.io/2016/01/24/implementing-android-mini-navigation-drawer.html?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4337

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this..

Add a vertical linear layout with icons to your root and align it start with required width.
Then set **visible** on drawer close and **gone** in drawer dragged/touched/opened

By default set visibility **gone**.